# UIResponder - didBecomeFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, uiresponder

is there any way to get notified when e.g. a UITextView becomes first responder? I'm currently subclassing & overriding `- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder` but the problem is that this happens *while* the view becomes first responder, not *after* it.

I have also tried KVC, but it doesn't work:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"isFirstResponder"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:NULL];
```

What technique should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use its delegate method textViewDidBeginEditing: ?

Comment: Hm, true! Maybe I should take a break... ^^